# How is this collatz conjecture?

Tags: mathematica, collatz-conjecture

In [this](https://youtu.be/Zp1EV7ytSnA?t=1879) video (don't have to see the video as I'm going to give the requierd info) the author defines the $collatz(x,y)$ function as below :

> If $x = 3y$ or $y = 3x$ or $x = 2y+1$ or $y = 2x+1$, then the value is $1$
>   otherwise the value is $0$.

Example :

> $collatz(27, 9)$ is $1$ because $27=3\times 9$
>   $collatz(5, 11)$ is $1$ because $11=2\times 5+1$
>   $collatz(5, 10)$ is $0$.

How on earth is above definition anyway related to [actual collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#Statement_of_the_problem) ?

Comment: What does it say about it in the video?

Comment: @saulspatz the author then plots the above function over $1\le x,y \le 500$ and generates a graph (binary tree kinda). I've got no clue what that means, still wondering...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Collatz conjecture becomes

> For any natural number $a$, there is a sequence $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$ of natural numbers such that
>   $$
> collatz(a, a_1) = 1\\
> collatz(a_1, a_2) = 1,\\
> \vdots\\
> collatz(a_{n-1}, a_n) = 1\\
> collatz(a_n, 1) = 1
> $$

And, as he draws the graph later, the conjecture becomes "Any number is connected to $1$ (assuming you draw the graph for large enough inputs)".

Except not really. This function represents a variation on the Collatz conjecture where you divide by $3$ when you can, and if not, you multiply by $2$ and add $1$, rather than divide by $2$ when you can and otherwise multiply by $3$ and add $1$. The tutor probably just got them mixed up.

Also, this function adds paths that would never be valid paths in the Collatz conjecture. For instance, even if you correct it to the right expression, we get that for instance $2$ and $7$ are connected, because $2$ becomes $7$ if we follow the incorrect path of multiplying by $3$ and adding $1$.

Comment: Ahh thank you :) so the author really got the function wrong. collatz(x, y) should really be :
$$$$
If $x=2y$ or $y=2x$ or $x=3y+1$ or $y=3x+1$, then the value is 1
otherwise the value is $0$

?
$$$$

Comment: @rsadhvika Yes, that's what the function ought to be. Note that, for instance, in the standard Collatz conjecture, the final loop is 1-4-2-1, while his graph showed 1 and 3 being connected.

Comment: Hey Arthur if I may ask a question, how are $8$ and $25$ related in collatz graph ? They are both connected because $25 = 8*3+1$. But they shouldn't be connected because from $8$ we go to $4$, and from $25$ we go to $76$. I don't see any connection between $8$ and $25$ even though the graph shows they are adjacent..

Comment: @rsadhvika Good question. That's something I should've caught myself. I edited in a comment about that to my answer.